# How to debug SSL Client authentication on Apache web server

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

Error is "SSL Library Error: error:140890C7:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate -- No CAs known to server for verification?"

Configuration:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile same as above
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem
SSLCACertificateFile my own self-signed CA cert file appended to fullchain.pem
SSLVerifyDepth 10
```

I have verified my self-signed client cert against my self-signed CA, and installed it in my browser (Chrome and Firefox)

I have tried:

- SSLCACertificateFile containing *only* my self-signed CA cert
- *without* SSLCertificate ChainFile (which seems redundant to me)

but always get the same error.

LogLevel warn ssl:debug and LogLevel warn ssl:trace6 don't provide any further clues.

So, to debug this, I need to see the server-client conversation in plain text but, of course, the connection is encrypted.

What tools are available?  How do the browser developers debug problems like this?

Comment: Hi Mike, did you find out? I am having the same issue, thanks